How can I Run/Extract/Or view a KPA file
I was coping files from a Dx3 VTech Watch and I found in the apps section a .kpa file and Im curious on how I can view it.
Ive noticed its a binary file
If you want to take a look at the files I uploaded some here:
Dx3/2 Apps
I tried searching up stuff relating to the file but I didn't find anything.
